# Flutter: Firestore how to retrieve all the collections belong to a document?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection tree like

```
- game (collection)
   - FPS (document)
      - CS:GO (collection)
      - Valorant (collection)
   - etc (document)
```

I am trying to retrieve all the collections from FPS but firebase is returning empty map {}.

Do I really have to make `.get()` operation to each collections, even if I just need collections that belong to `FPS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Currently, you can't query multiple collections at once.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your structure to:

```
 Genres(collection)
     FPS(document)
        Games(collection)
          CS:GO(document)
          Valorant(document)
     MOBA(document)
        Games(collection)
          LOL(document)
          Dota 2(document)
```

For each game genre, you will have a collection of games. In this way you can get all documents inside `("Genres/FPS/Games")`

Comment: Thanks u for the suggestion! I’m moving from MongoDb and trying to get used to this. I will try ur suggestion!